# Why doesn't express handle throw new error?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a `server.js` with the typical express configuration, as well as a separate `routes.js` to handle the routes.

`server.js`

```
...

app.use('/', router);

app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  console.error(err);
  res.status(500).render('error-server', {
    layout: 'main',
    title: 'Server Error'
  });
});

...
```

`routes.js`

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

router.get('/what', function (req, res) {
  throw new Error('BROKEN'); // works, throws the error that is handled in server.js
});


router.get('/test', (req, res) => {
  fetch('wrong_url_to_test_error_handling')
  .then(checkStatus)
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(json => console.log(json));

  res.send('Ok');
});

function checkStatus(res) {
  if (res.ok) {
    return res;
  } else {
    throw new Error('BROKEN'); // this does not work
  }
}
```

The `/what` route properly handles the error, however the `/test` route does not. The fetch fails the `checkStatus` function and the else statement is fired, but the error throwing is not handled the same way as the error for the `/what` route. Is there a reason for this?

Thanks :)

Comment: I'm not sure, but don't you need to pass `res` to checkStatus? Have you put a `console.log('test')` to ensure the else statement is executing? I don't think you're executing the function there...

Comment: Yes, the `res` for the `checkStatus` has been logged to confirm it is working. Here is the `res` when it fails: https://gist.github.com/SamSverko/4e58d07fa2f87703523247e2e560142d

Comment: I can also confirm the error is throwing, because it appears in the error log, it's just not reaching the express error handler on the `server.js` file for some reason...

Comment: Well... As far as I know the express error handler requires you to call `next(err)` in the middleware chain after catching the error. Have you read the [docs?](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html)

Comment: I've tried implementing next as per express' documentation on handling async errors, but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are throwing inside a promise chain and, as you have no `.catch`, the error gets swallowed.

That's why it doesn't reach the Express error handler.

In this case, you will need to forward the error to the `next` function by chaining `.catch`:

```
router.get('/test', (req, res, next) => {
  fetch('wrong_url_to_test_error_handling')
    .then(checkStatus)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(json => {
      console.log(json)
      res.send('Ok')
    })
    .catch(next)
})
```

Comment: That worked! I tried adding in a catch, but didn't throw in the res.send into the previous `.then()`.
(I also had to add `next` as a parameter to the `router.get()`.
Thank you so much :)